# Not able to package project using Maven

Tags: java, maven, maven-2

I am trying to package my project using maven. I have looked at many of the questions but none could help me and moreover, I am quite a newbie to this. When I try to execute the command "mvn clean package" inside my project directory, I get the following error:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for com.cognitionis:tipsem:jar:2.5
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin is missing. @ line 48, column 21
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[WARNING] 
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building TIPSem 2.5
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/2.5/maven-clean-plugin-2.5.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.653s
[INFO] Finished at: Sat Jun 11 00:29:54 IST 2016
[INFO] Final Memory: 7M/102M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:jar:2.5: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:pom:2.5 from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Connection to http://repo.maven.apache.org refused: Connection refused -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginResolutionException
```

I have installed maven version 3.0.5 and I have included this version number in pom.xml as well. Can you guys please help me with this.

Comment: Can you open the url http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/2.5/maven-clean-plugin-2.5.pom in your browser? Do you have an unrestricted internet connection?

Comment: This looks to to be the cause "Connection to http://repo.maven.apache.org refused: Connection refused" - as @dunni suggests, try the url in your browser to confirm connectivity. Do you have a connection to the internet? Is there any firewall or proxy between your PC and the internet?

Comment: Yes. I do have proxy setting but I was able to open the URL in my browser.

Comment: But your proxy configuration in your `settings.xml` seemed to be wrong, cause the download does not work. Are you sure you are using the correct `settings.xml`?

Answer (score 0):

If you are working in any organization where they generally restrict to access sites/repositories in internet, if yours is having any kind of security policies,

I suggest you to check with others whether your organization have any internal nexus or some other maven repository already in place, If so you need to configure the repository in your .m2/settings.xml .

If not as @Kevin Hooke told check for any internal firewall or proxy settings.

Comment: But I am able to access the URL in my browser. I have a proxy setting but I don't think that it's the cause.

Comment: In your browser the configuration for Proxy / Firewall is already done. The proxy configuration in Maven has to be done correctly in `settings.xml`...